# What is the max count of id in ids query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm going to store search results for complex queries as a list of ids to perform aggregations some time ago.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

What is the max count of ids in ids query can I send?

Answer (score 1):

The default limit is 1024. But you can increase it with by changing the settings in **elasticsearch.yml**

> indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10000

More info on the subject here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-settings.html

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/index-query-bool-max-clause-count-Setting-and-TermsQueryParser-td3050751.html

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/482

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/index-query-bool-max-clause-count-Setting-and-TermsQueryParser-td3050751.html

Comment: I mean, count of id in ids query. I can send 2000 ids with default settings.

Comment: Now I found only one restriction: http.max_content_length 100Mb for Ids. My system returns and builds reports for 500 000 ids with no problem.